# Find element in jQuery with dynamic value

Tags: jquery

I have following jquery script

```
var $checked = $inputs.filter(':checked');
var numChecked = $checked.length;

$checked.each(function () {
    var val = (this).value;

    if (val.indexOf("Ya") != -1) {
        alert('old val   ' + val);
        val = val.replace("Ya", "Y2a");
        alert('new val   ' + val);
        alert($(':input[value^="' + val + '"]').value);

        //$(val).attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true })[flag ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('ui-state-disabled');
    }
});
```

**the old value is** : ltrYaxis0

**the new value is** : ltrY2axis0

I am able to replace 
but when I am trying to test whether its finding the new input or not, its saying **undefined**.
I have to make this hidden or  disable

Comment: can you show us the html of the element you're trying to match?

Comment: You want to find input with "Ya" value, replace it's value and find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trye this

```
 val = val.replace("Ya", "Y2a");
       $(':input[value='+val + ']'.attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the requirement correctly, this will do

```
var $checked = $inputs.filter(':checked');
var numChecked = $checked.length;

$checked.filter(function () {
    return this.value.indexOf("Ya") != -1;
}).val(function (idx, val) {
    return val.replace("Ya", "Y2a");
}).attr({
    'disabled': true,
    'aria-disabled': true
})[flag ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('ui-state-disabled');
```

Comment: what do you mean by jquery failed to load

Comment: please just tell me how to find the element with dynamic value

Comment: look at the first part of the script `$checked.filter(function () {
    return this.value.indexOf("Ya") != -1;
})`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var val = (this).value;
```

has 2 errors.

- You missed the $
- and not .value but .val()

  ```
  var val = $(this).val();
  ```

and be careful :

```
    $(val).attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true })
```

it shoul be

```
$(this).attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true }) ...
```